# Download Manager: STATUS HTTP DATA ERROR: failed to connect to web server from mobile device ip address android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to use to download an image from my localhost web server using `DownloadManager`. The code works fine when trying to download some files from other websites, but the problem when I try to download an image from my own localhost server. Given that I can access the image from android device browser.

I've searched on the internet about the `HTTP_DATA_ERROR`, but couldn't find anything that would solve my problem.

Here's the code that I use to download the image:

```
public void downLoadContactsImages(String url, Context context, 
    DownloadManager.Request request){
SharedPreferences login = context.getSharedPreferences( "Login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
String pass = login.getString( USER_PASS, USER_PASS );
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyApp/");

Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse( url );
request = new DownloadManager.Request(
        downloadUri
);
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
File directory = cw.getDir("channel" + "1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdir();
}
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);


String imgnm = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
String startdownloadurl = directory.getAbsolutePath()+"/";
System.out.println(" directory " + startdownloadurl);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(imgnm)
        .setDescription("Downloading...")
        .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(startdownloadurl, imgnm);
```

}

here's what I get in my log:

```
`DownloadManager: [1223]: Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: failed to connect to /192.168.43.85 (port 3000) from /10.116.136.147 (port (43241)`
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: The only explanation I could come up to, is that maybe DownloadManager supports a certain type of servers, that's why it's refusing to connect to my machine server

Comment: The obvious underlying problem from the error you've shown is that you're trying to reach a private network address (192.168.x.x) from a different private network (10.x.x.x).  Unless the infrastructure is specifically set up to handle that, it's not going to work.  There will be no working route between those IP addresses.  When you say "your own localhost server", what exactly do you mean?  A server on the device itself?  That would normally be addressed as 127.0.0.1.